# Запрет вывода промежуточных результатов fzero

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте, у меня есть m-функция с шестью входными параметрами:

```
function rp = func_rp( dV,i,U,a,b,v )
```

dV - приращение скорости
i,U,a,b,v - углы, характеризующие точку, в которой будет дан импульс и направление импульса.
Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы найти для каждой пары (i,U) минимальный по модулю вектор скорости, (a,b) - углы, характеризующие направление импульса скорости, dV - непосредственно модуль, v - угол точки, в которой дан импульс.
Если кто-то может подсказать как это сделать с помощью каких либо методов оптимизации, подскажите пожалуйста. Так как я не знаю таких методов, я хочу все проитерировать, то есть составить 5 циклов в корне которого ищу dV с помощью fzero, а потом искать минимальный импульс из полученных данных. В общем:

```
dVoporn=0.8;
dVmin=Inf;
dVout=[0;0];
degrees=0:1*pi/180:359*pi/180;
for a=degrees
    dVopt=fzero(@(dV) rp(dV,0,0,a,0,128*pi/180),dVoporn);
    if abs(dVopt)<abs(dVmin);
        dVout=[dVopt;a];
        dVmin=dVopt;
    end
end
dVout
```

Этот один цикл работает около минуты, что катастрофически много, и основное время у меня тратится на выдачу в окно консоли промежуточных результатов:

```
rp =

  -28.0246


 rp =

  -10.6622


rp =

    0.0077


rp =

  -4.1855e-06


rp =

  -2.0009e-11
```

И так много много раз:

[image: Время выполнения]

Как можно убрать эти промежуточные выводы?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема видится в том, что в определении функции rp опущена точка-с-запятой в конце одной строки. Это означает, что результат вычисления в этой строке выдаётся на экран. Поправить легко:

```
function rp = rp(...) 
  ...
  rp = rpZ - Ratm;     % added semicolon
end
```